# Deploy Django App to Render as a static site

Tags: python, django

Anyone kind enough to tell me what should the build command be? Also what should there be in the publish directory (I named it dist and it has an empty index.html). My build script right now is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# exit on error
set -o errexit

python manage.py collectstatic --no-input
python manage.py migrate
```